# Form to dynamically change size according to its contained elements

Tags: html, forms, css

I would like to make a dynamic form, that is, the form will change its size dynamically, according to the elements contained within it. 
[code example](http://codepen.io/BusyBee/pen/WrKEav)

```css
.myForm {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  color:grey;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  background:#ECEEE9;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
<form class="myForm" id="noteForm" name="noteForm" METHOD="POST">
  <h1>Add a note</h1>
  <h2>Formatting</h2>
</form>
```

The outer sides of the form (border if you may) should just wrap around the text nicely, when the text gets longer, the form gets longer... at the moment it is just too wide to my liking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add  display: inline-block; to .myForm